# Trying to run a cloned project with gradle but unable to build

Tags: spring-boot, github, gradle, intellij-idea

I have cloned a Spring boot project from github and I have opened it in intellij. So I am trying to run the build.gradle but I just get this error:

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.boot', version: '2.3.3.RELEASE']

Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.boot']

Spring Boot plugin requires Gradle 5 (5.6.x only) or Gradle 6 (6.3 or later). The current version is Gradle 5.2

This is the plugin:

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
id 'java'
}
```

What is going on here?

Comment: in `Build > Execution, Deployment > Builds Tools > Gradle` are you using the  `wrapper`?

Answer (score 0):

You have Gradle version 5.2.  The error states that the Spring Boot plugin specifically requires either 5.6.x (e.g., 5.6.4) or a version greater than or equal to 6.3 (e.g., 6.3, 6.6.1).

You need to [upgrade your Gradle version](https://gradle.org/releases/) to a 5.6 variant or a newer version that is greater than or equal to 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure a Gradle version for a project to be 5.6.x only or 6.3 or later:

[image]

If wrapper.properties is used for the project the Gradle version is saved in the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in the `gradle` directory of your project.

See detailed steps at [Configure a Gradle version for a project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#gradle_version_install)
 documentation page.